# Application installing another application on the emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

How should I organize applications A a B to make application A to install the application B, both on the android emulator on the same computer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer to this question: [Install Application programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android). You can only initiate installation of an application from Android Market

Comment: Market is an application, too. If it can install, any app can install. Of course, with asking the user for a consent. I am not talking about ways of installing. I am talking about organizing/placement of the both application in the computer while debugging on the emulator.

Comment: Market has priveledges to background install that general API does not allow.  You need a custom system image to do what you are wanting to do.