# How to link download of one application with another

Tags: android, open-intents

I want to use some applications from openintents (http://www.openintents.org/en/) but is there is way to have where installing one application will also install, or at least download, other applications?

For example, if the program is going to be relying on the OpenIntents File Manager (http://www.openintents.org/en/filemanager) then I could just look for the existence of that application, then suggest that they download it, with a url, perhaps, but that seems like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that i know.

In a perfect Android world all filemanagers would support a standard set of Intents so it shouldn't matter which one is installed. Of course it's not that way (yet?).

So your are left with those two: [Install Application programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android/4604922#4604922)

Comment: Thank you, guess I will look and try to do it programmatically if it is needed.