# Android marketplace link

Tags: android, hyperlink, google-play, android-webview

I think I would like users to be directed to the marketplace for an "in-app update" I am creating.

On iOS there are itunes://url  style links that takes users to the itunes store. This is also recognized on windows if you have itunes installed.

So I am wondering if there is a way to invoke the android marketplace via a specially formatted link from within another app or in a webview (within an app)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android/4604922#4604922

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
market://details?id=com.example.your.package
```