# Install intent for local .apk file on gingerbread

Tags: android, android-intent, installation

When I installed new APK from another App on Android 2.1, I just used:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent2);
```

It opened new install dialog and i could use it.

Now, I try the same code on Gingerbread 2.3.3, and when I start this install intent, it shows me a selection "select action using application". With the following choices: Google talk, video, videotalk, DRM, Market.

What happened? Did the install intents changed in Gingerbread? How to make new install intent at Android Gingerbread? Thanks

Comment: Try creating the `File` object using the appropriate `File` constructor rather than string concatenation, and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope, problem is that it looks like Android 2.3 doesn't know the corresponding MIME type...

Comment: [`PackageInstaller` does](http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/AndroidManifest.xml&exact_package=android&q=application/vnd.android.package-archive&type=cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API reference [says](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/10/changes/alldiffs_index_changes.html) that there weren't any changes applied in startActivity(Intent) method. ACTION_VIEW launches the default activity to handle a piece of data or asks to choose one to make default (as I see). If you are getting the list of apps to launch then you don't have default action for this type of data. Also, check if non-market apps are enabled to be installed on your device.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I am trying it on emulator and on the phone Galaxy S, still having the same issue. I have non-market apps install enabled, really don't know what is the problem

Comment: @Hmyzak, can you try using ACTION_GET_CONTENT instead of current action? (Unfortunately I don't have anything around me to test.)

Comment: I have tried it and it is not the solution, I am getting error of ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android/4605040#4605040 take a look at this discussion too

Comment: THanks for comment, but it didn't helped :-(