# Hosting APK + Updates?

Tags: android, air

I have an app written in Adobe Air (actionscript3) then packaged as an APK for the moto xoom (android os, using flashdevlop).

We are looking to host both the install and update. There are no issues with selecting unknown sources. And installing from web works but i cant seem to find anyway to set it up to find updates thru my server or the correct way to push those updates. Thoughts or links, google has failed me?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to make clear i need it to work thru the built in update checking so it will auto update if the device is set to do this. By default either the app or device is checking for updates somewhere. I want to change where it checks for that update and what format/syntax its expecting.

Comment: "built in update checking" are you talking about the option in the Android Market...

Comment: @l_39217_l yes, i'm wondering if there is a way to point an APK at some place different. By default either the device or app is checking if there is an update somewhere. I'm wondering if i can change where the points to and what the format for that file it.

Comment: Did you heard about PushLink https://push-link.com/ Very nice alternative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in update check is the Android Market app, pinging the Android Market server to check for updates.  Since you're not distributing your app through Market, there's no way for you to take advantage of its update mechanism-  You'll have to write your own (Amazon's market app, by way of example, does this).

Essentially you'll have to set up some sort of alert mechanism (check for updates on app startup, maybe), download the APK, and fire an intent to have the user explicitly state they want to install the app.  Auto updating (downloading and installing the APK without the user doing anything at all) isn't possible outside of Android Market, for security reasons.

For more information on how to fire the "install" activity, check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android).

Comment: Thanks, my issue is since its built in flash i cant add android code. I'm toying with the idea of a second helper app built native with android but im not sure with the sandbox if i can write and install an app outside my sandbox. Any thoughts on if that might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a good case for cloud to device messaging....to notify the user of the update 
is available...

http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

I think they will still have to download/install it.....You can help them by making the download/install feature of the app it self.....

Comment: I forgot to make clear i need it to work thru the built in update checking so it will auto update if the device is set to do this. Apps thru the store do this by default, im trying to figure out how to do it thru my own server as well.

Answer (score 0):

okey... i think you have a few web services right... create a update webservice that takes in the user version and sends it to you.. you can cross reference it and if the user needs to download a new version they get directed to a browser ... where you can poit to where you host the files... you can put in a menu item in the app to say allow the user to check for any upgrades... version number of the app can be got easily... check google or get back to me if you still are nunable to find any...

Comment: I forgot to make clear i need it to work thru the built in update checking so it will auto update if the device is set to do this. Apps thru the store do this by default, im trying to figure out how to do it thru my own server as well.

Comment: perfect.... write out your line of for update in an async task... take the version number from the clients app... send it to your webservice and then if the version is smaller then push a new version which is greater. as simple as that.... only drawback is you cannot push your version number lower with this methodology///...  and once the app client is pushed a website then they can be downloaded from the website .... in a browser. and installed from there... if it is only for testing purpose... just put your file in any shared public shared location and give it to clients. to test it...