# auto installing not working in android

Tags: android

i am working on the project named AutoUpdate with package name:com.example.
and the apk i am having in my sd card also having same package name :com.example
this is my method which is called for instaling the apk.the apk file is in sd card.my code is as:

```
private void installMarketApk() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myapp.apk";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

my manifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.custom.activity.mspresentation.AutoUpdateDemoActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

when i run this application i am prompted to Replace application dialog "The application you are trying will replace another another application".so i just click ok for installing application.
now i got do you want to install this application .this will change to :
1.Storage
2.network communication
3.phone calls 
.......
with install and cancel options.
now i choose install,a progress bar appears with initialising and **APPLICATION NOT INSTALLED**.
if i have to give some permissions in manifest file?
ANY SUGGESTION ?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"></uses-permission>

Comment: uninstall previous app with same package name and then try again..because sometimes you can't override existing app with same package but different signature

Comment: @Maneesh thanks for your reply!yes packages are same what do you mean by signature?

Comment: An app is uniquely identified by its package name and the key by which is signed, by default android default key is used to sign the app, and a signature will embed in apk file which identify the app

Comment: @PadmaKumar thanks for pointing out the error !still not able to install it.

Comment: @Maneesh thanks for this information,however the apks i am working on are simple binaries not any involvement from market.

Comment: try changing the apk. may be some time copying the apk to external will be corrupted. Can u send the error log once.

Comment: thanks padam ,i dont know what the problem was there /or i was not able to.but i make a new apk and try,it worked thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be it would be helping some one:
the apk package names and target names should be shame,it was in my case.

i have deleted the previous .apk from sd card and put a new apk(may be currupted or project properties was not matching).

dont be confuse from installMarketApp here.i just put apk manually in sd card.

private void installMarketApk() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myapp.apk";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)),   "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the following permissions in your Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

It will allow your code "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" to access your SD card storage to access the api you are trying to install.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i dont thing any requirement for this permission because i am alredy getting apk version name,code number and package information programmatically using getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo

Comment: If you have not solved this problem yet, have a look at the following links. I hope It explains how to install an app programatically.  1) .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android                                                                                                                                              2). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically

Comment: thanks for the link ....my apk was corrupt !i just have to replace my apk with new one