# Download Application and Install Dynamically on Android

Tags: android, installation

How to download application given URL and setup on android?

Example:

When the application runs, it will first control the web service to ask for a new application.

If there are any new applications, it will get the URL, downloads the file and install.

How can it be done?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android

Answer (score 3):

You cannot install APKs that way -- only applications that are part of the system firmware can do that.

You should be able to use an `ACTION_VIEW` Intent, with a MIME type of application/vnd.android.package-archive and a Uri pointing to your file. Note that this may not work on devices that do not have "allow non-Market installs" checked.

Comment: I checked "allow non-Market installs". Download and save apk in code. After run this code but i get package decomposion error  File fullPath = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "example.apk");        
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fullPath), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);