# Can We Install an APK From a ContentProvider?

Tags: android

I am working on [a library to allow apps to self-update](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater), for those that are being distributed outside of the Android Market.

My original plan was to include code that would download the APK file to internal storage, and then install it from there via a `ContentProvider` and a `content://` `Uri`. However, when I tried that, the installer system dumped a "Skipping dir: " warning to LogCat and failed to actually install it. Once I switched to downloading the APK to external storage and using a `file://` `Uri` with the `ACTION_VIEW` installer `Intent`, it worked.

The "Skipping dir:" message seems to be logged by `parsePackage()` in `PackageParser`, which seems to assume that it is working with a `File`. That would suggest that we cannot use `content://` `Uri` values.

Has anyone successfully used `ACTION_VIEW` on a `application/vnd.android.package-archive` `Intent` with a `content://` `Uri`? If so, was there some specific trick in setting up the `ContentProvider` that made it work?

Thanks!

Comment: and how excatly this ContentProvider looks (specially openFile implementation)?

Comment: @Selvin: A `ContentProvider` with an `openFile()` implementation is what's needed to allow files to be served, and I used [an existing trivial implementation that I know works in general](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ContentProvider/Files) as the basis. My question is whether anyone has successfully gotten this to work, as my reading of the source code suggests that it is not supported, regardless of what the `ContentProvider` looks like.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but have you seen the method described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4605040/377260

Comment: @iPaulPro: That would only work if you were building firmware.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would assume this is not possible, as the Java API doesn't seem to allow it.  ContentProvider's `openFile()` returns a `ParcelFileDescriptor`, from which you can obtain a `java.io.FileDescriptor`.  You can then use this `FileDescriptor` to open either a `FileInputStream` or a `FileOutputStream`.  Unfortunately, you can't use it to open a `RandomAccessFile` (despite the fact that `RandomAccessFile` works on descriptors just the same as the others, the constructor you'd need is just missing from the API).

As APK files are ZIP files, which must be read out of order (you have to seek to the end to find the file directory), I assume the implementation of installation will require a `RandomAccessFile`, so it would not have been possible to support the case you're trying to implement.

Comment: I agree with your assessment, but while your analysis went down a different path than mine, it's still pretty much where I am -- "well, it doesn't *look* possible". I'm holding out for something a bit more definitive. :-) I'll accept your answer, though, if I don't get something better. Thanks!

Comment: The PackageManagerService which handles installation creates a copy of the APK file and so does not require the original URI to provide a stream with seeking ability.

Comment: I've read the inside of zips via a content provider (I download addons for one of my projects and they consist of a zip provided by a content provider).

Comment: Note that Android 7.0+ supports `content` `Uri` values now.

Answer (score 27):

The documentation for ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE is incorrect. It too will only accept files.

My only suggestion would therefore be to create a copy of the file in the applications file area, make it world readable, and clean up any left-over files at a later date.

> **Previous incorrect answer**: In 4.0 and above there is a
>   ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE which will accept a content:// URI 
>   ([JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)), but, prior to that, you're limited to installing via
>   ACTION_VIEW which does assume the URI passed is a file:// URI.

Comment: Have you tried this? I get the same results as with `ACTION_VIEW` when I use a `content://` scheme -- a "Skipping dir" LogCat message, and the installer bails.

Comment: I had faith in the documentation, but it would appear that the documentation is wrong. The code servicing ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE will only accept files as well. Time to register a bug. Sorry.

Comment: Well, at least I'm not completely crazy, then. Incompletely crazy, most certainly. :-) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note: the `content` scheme works on Android 7.0, though not on previous versions of Android.

Comment: IMPORTANT - `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` is deprecated and (from documentation:) "As of [Android] N attempting to use this mode will throw a SecurityException". I used `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` to let the system access the dowloaded APK-file in the app's private storage-directory so I didn't need the permission for external storage but as of Android 7 this is no longer possible!

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Jules analysis, and I would add concrete precisions :

In `PackageInstallerActivity`, which is called by ACTION_VIEW on an apk, there is this in the `onCreate()` method:

```
315 String apkPath = mPackageURI.getPath();
316 File apkFile = new File(apkPath);
```

And before that, this method from `PackageUtil` is called:

```
73 public static  PackageParser.Package getPackageInfo(Uri packageURI) {
74     final String archiveFilePath = packageURI.getPath();
75     PackageParser packageParser = new PackageParser(archiveFilePath);
76     File sourceFile = new File(archiveFilePath);
77     DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
78     metrics.setToDefaults();
79     return packageParser.parsePackage(sourceFile, archiveFilePath, metrics, 0);
80 }
```

All this tends to confirm that the PackageManager do expects only File Uris.

The log you have, `Skipping dir:` is found in `packageParser.parsePackage`, which tests whether the path given in the Uri is a file or not.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in one of my applications which allows me access to local storage (user preference selectable before you have a go at me ;) )

```
import java.io.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.database.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class LocalFileContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
   private static final String URI_PREFIX = "content://your.content.provider.as.per.manifest";

   public static String constructUri(String url) {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
       return uri.isAbsolute() ? url : URI_PREFIX + url;
   }

   @Override
   public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {

       SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

       boolean allowLocal = app_preferences.getBoolean("allowLocalFiles", false);

        if (allowLocal) {    
            try {
                File file = new File(uri.getPath());

                if (file.isDirectory())
                    return null;

                ParcelFileDescriptor parcel = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
                return parcel;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreate() {
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] as) {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
   }

   @Override
   public String getType(Uri uri) {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
   }

   @Override
   public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues) {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
   }

   @Override
   public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] as, String s, String[] as1, String s1) {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
   }

   @Override
   public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentvalues, String s, String[] as) {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported by this provider");
   }

}
```

My manifest contains

```
<provider android:name="it.automated.android.kiosk.se.LocalFileContentProvider"
      android:authorities="it.automated" />
```

and then to start the install (or action)

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
viewIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), mimeType);
```

Comment: I will try that again. Your code is nearly identical to what I started with, which failed with the results as described in the question itself. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is not on the provider side, so even if you used the API Demos code (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/FileProvider.html) the issue would still persist.

Comment: You can use a WebView as an intermediary which works perfectly well.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare I'm new here and beginner in android too, i just need your a little bit assistance regarding your question , can you brief me with  a detailed reply how can i install another app with the help of an app, like by storing the .apk into an app etc

Comment: in short i want to bind an apk with another apk to install, is it possible? if possible with latest versions ,plz let me know how is it