# How to launch the stock installer app in android

Tags: android, android-intent, installation, protocols

I used to have this problem but I found a solution, so just decided to post it here just in case someone else needs it.

How to launch the native installer app to install an apk?

Many posts have the solution as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This is fine except a tiny but crutial detail:

the "path" string must start with **file://** otherwise you'll get an exception such as

```
Unable to find an activity to handle the intent .....
```

So make sure the **path starts with *file://***

Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637629/can-we-install-an-apk-from-a-contentprovider

Comment: @CommonsWare - your link does indeed contain this information, however does not put stress on the importance of "file://" scheme. Thanks for the link by the way, I wish I could find it earlier - would save me a bunch of grey hair :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, instead of using the [parse(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) method, you can simply use the [fromFile(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile%28java.io.File%29) method of the [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) class (the Uri will automatically have the form *"file://"*).

Thus:

```
final File file = new File(path);
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
context.startActivity(intent);
```