# Installing apk without user input

Tags: android, operating-system, apk

I have been searching the internet wildly for an answer to this question.

We are creating custom android app for internal use only and we would be installing that on custom andoid devices. We would like to have full control of the device through the app. The end user of this device is not meant to use anything other than the app on this device. I have sealed out all the possibilities of getting out of the app except this one possibility where the program tries to update itself and asks for user permission.

Let me repeat again, This app is not meant to be put on market, only for use with custom devices designed for specific purpose. So security is not an issue here. 
The device is rooted and we have done a lot of alterations with it. But I cant quite figure out how to make this update work.

If you have any ideas/solution please share it with me. I can do anything with my device, (even dig a hole in it if required :P) as they would be custom made, and would be packaged with us before going out. Just have to make it work.

Comment: how can i code that in my app ? This device wont be connected to a computer. all it has is internet access once it is out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about internally installing the APK with like an update application specifically designed to update your other application which is not managed by Google Play you may want to look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android). So between xjaphx's answer and the link I just shared you will be able to install and maintain updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as how it works.

Pre-condition:

- Get devices rooted
- Prepare Android development environment (Android SDK, platforms-tools)
- A cable to connect PC and devices.

Steps:

- Open command-line if Windows or shell if Linux
- type: "adb push YourApp.apk /system/app"

That's done for installation of the app. Reboot and check whether your app works or not.

Comment: Pretty sure the OP meant for this to be done from a device that isn't connected to a computer.

Comment: true. My device wont be connected to a computer after it goes out. All i have is my app code and wifi access.

Comment: I've never done it myself, but I believe there are ways you can use ADB over wifi.

Comment: Awesome. Never thought of that. It seems there are options for using ADB over wifi. Also the other option of writing an app that does nothing except updating the main app. Thanks for all the replies. Will explore between the two options.