# Android custom permissions - Marshmallow

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

*Background*

Historically, Android Custom permissions [have been a mess](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65864) and [were install order dependent](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25906), which was known to [expose vulnerabilities](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/02/12/vulnerabilities-custom-permissions.html).

Prior to API 21, there was an unsettling workaround whereby declaring the custom permission of another application in your Manifest, granted the permission... However, since API 21, only one application can declare a custom permission and the installation of a further application declaring this same permission, will be prevented.

The alternatives are to reinstall the application requiring the permission, so they are detected by the System, but that [is not a good user experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620464/reinstall-application-apk-programmatically-without-downloading). Or check at runtime for the permissions of the calling application, but [that is not without its theoretical flaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573139/programmatically-alter-manifest-android-custom-permissions).

*Problem*

As of Android Marshmallow (6.0 - API 23) an application needs to request permission from the user, **to use its own custom permission**. A declared custom permission is not automatically granted.

This seems peculiar, given that only one application can now declare it.

*To replicate*

Declare the custom permission and a BroadcastReceiver in the Manifest.

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP"
    android:description="@string/control_description"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/control_label"
    android:protectionLevel="normal or dangerous"/>

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP"/>

// etc

<receiver
    android:name="com.example.app.MyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="com.example.app.REQUEST_RECEIVER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

From a third-party application, declare that it uses the custom permission in the Manifest (and accept it via a dialog or the settings) and call:

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.app.REQUEST_RECEIVER");

    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, "com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP", new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        // getResultCode();

        }
    }, null, Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, null, null);
```

The result will return CANCELED and the log will show:

> system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent {
>   act=com.example.app.REQUEST_RECEIVER flg=0x10 (has extras) } to
>   com.example.app/.MyBroadcastReceiver requires
>   com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP due to sender
>   com.example.thirdparty

If I use the standard `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` dialog to allow the user to accept the permission, the receiver, as you would expect, works correctly.

*Question*

**Is this expected behaviour? Or have I somehow overlooked something?**

It would seem ridiculous to raise a dialog saying

> The application Example App wants permission to use Example App

And it may indeed concern the user, providing them with such a nonsensical request.

I can of course change the permission description and name, to something that they would accept, such as '*communicate with other installed applications*', but before I sigh and take that approach, I thought I'd ask this question.

*Note*

The example of the ordered broadcast is to replicate the problem. My application does use other implementations of content providers and a bound service. It is not an alternative implementation I require, it's confirmation of the issue.

Thank you for reading this far.

**Edit:** To clarify, for other implementations, such as declaring a permmission on a Service (which would be most simple to replicate) the declared custom permission is automatically granted.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce your problem, at least on Android 7.1 (Google Pixel). I copied your code into a new Android Studio project and have no problems sending a broadcast from the client to the receiver and getting a response. Now, my sample may be simpler than yours (e.g., both apps are signed by the same signing key). If you can create a sample app that consistently reproduces this problem, and you can reproduce it on 7.1, [file an issue](http://b.android.com) against the developer preview, including the sample app and full instructions.

Comment: Just to be clear , are you asking for guideline how to request permission from user in a reasonable way that , he will not deny ? or are you asking to propose a solution for when he reject your permission what could be the possibilities ? i'm confused

Comment: I think that the fact that the app requests its own permission can be interpreted as a "master switch", something like: "let other apps control this app". And even though the permission must be granted in third party apps (too) to be able to control the example app, some users might actually be using it to disallow the "controllability" feature completely. (But still odd, that a service for example gets the custom permission automatically...)

Answer (score 3):

As I understood you tried to do next thing (At least, that's how I was able to reproduce your problem):

1. You declare your new custom permission in first (lets call it F) application

   ```
   <permission
       android:name="com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP"
       android:description="@string/control_description"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/control_label"
       android:protectionLevel="normal or dangerous"/>
   ```
2. You define that your F app uses `com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP` permission. That is right as the guideline says.

   ```
   <uses-permission
       android:name="com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP"/>
   ```
3. You declare your custom broadcast receiver in your F app. To communicate with that broadcast your app (it's no matter which one, F or other app) must obtain your custom permission

   ```
   <receiver
       android:name="com.example.app.MyBroadcastReceiver"
       android:permission="com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP">
       <intent-filter android:priority="999">
           <action android:name="com.example.app.REQUEST_RECEIVER"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
4. You define that you second (lets call it S) application uses `com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP` permission. Because you want to allow S app to send broadcast messages to F app receiver.

   ```
   <uses-permission
       android:name="com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP"/>
   ```
5. Finally you try to send broadcast message from your S app using this code.

   ```
   final Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.app.REQUEST_RECEIVER");
   context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, "com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP", new BroadcastReceiver() {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
               // getResultCode();
           }
       }, null, Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, null, null);
   ```

   And, **this is important**, you granted permission to your S app, but you didn't grant permission to your F app.

   As result your broadcast receiver declared in F app didn't receive anything.
6. After you granted permission to your F app (Note that now S and F granted your custom permission) everything works fine. Broadcast receiver declared in F app received message from S app.

I guess that is correct behaviour, because this [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms) says us:

> Note that, in this example, the DEBIT_ACCT permission is not only
>   declared with the  element, its use is also requested with
>   the  element. You must request its use in order for
>   other components of the application to launch the protected activity,
>   even though the protection is imposed by the application itself.

And app which declare permission also must request the same permission to communicate with itself.

As result, android API 23 should to get access to use your permission form user first. And we must to get 2 granted permissions, first from F app (because guidline says as that) and second from S app (because we just need to get access).

But I didn't catch your next point:

> It would seem ridiculous to raise a dialog saying
>
> > The application Example App wants permission to use Example App

My native Android API 23 displays me something like that:

> The application Example App wants

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your example is that you explicitly require that *both* your applications are granted the custom permission.

This part requires, that the *com.example.thirdparty* app has the permission:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.app.MyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP">
```

And this part requires, that the *com.example.app* application has the permission as well:

```
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, "com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP", ...
```

You mention that you don't have this problem when using a service. I don't know how exactly you use the service, but if you simply declare it like this:

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.app.MyService"
    android:permission="com.example.app.permission.CONTROL_EXAMPLE_APP">
```

and then bind it like this:

```
context.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection, ...
```

then it's enough if *com.example.thirdparty* has the permission granted, while *com.example.app* doesn't need to have it.

In other words, I think this behavior is by design, and the difference you see between the Broadcast and Service behavior is because in the Broadcast case you specifically request that the *com.example.app* has the custom permission, whereas in the Service case you don't.

I hope I didn't misunderstand your problem. If I did, please let me know and I'll delete this response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's completely true that a declared custom permission will not be automatically granted to the application. For when the custom permission has the protection level "normal" or "signature", then the permission is granted at install time. Otherwise, if the protection level is "dangerous", then it is a runtime permission and it works just like other dangerous permissions: you will need to prompt the user to grant the permission to the application.

Answer (score -1):

While it might be ambiguous for the user to see a permission request for the app which is declared in the same app, it is how android is designed to run since marshmallow. I think, on android's perspective, the behavior is as intended and correct.

Comment: This statement cannot be correct, since the Custom Permission is automatically granted in other circumstances - therefore it is not universally 'by design'

Answer (score -2):

First add permissions in manifest file after

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```