# How to update the pre-installed application programmatically in android

Tags: android

I am working on an app where app installs .apk file which is available on my local server.
 and if there is any update notification for the installed local server application,its need to update the application. I am using GCM to send notification to the android device for update and get the **versionCode** from notification and compare it with the installed .apk version. Upto this things are right. But I stuck with  how to update the per-installed local server application so that its setting doesn’t changes.

THANKS.

Comment: I think if the package name remains same, the app will be updated automatically when you install your update

Comment: thanks, its means i have to only installed the new version .apk file.and what abt previous app setting

Comment: It'll remain the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Does Android application work as client for your server? If this is the case, I do not recommend you to use server-side pushes for update notifications. If notification fails to reach device (AFAIK, official documentation says, that this is normal behavior), user will have outdated version. It is better to check for new version periodically/on every access to server and download/install apk as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android). You may also want to look at [source code of FDroid](https://gitorious.org/f-droid/), which consist of server- and client-side components and can fetch, download and install updates for number of applications.