# Silent install apk programmatically by system app (without root)

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I have system-level app with android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" (UID: 1000).

Device is not rooted! INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is included to Manifest.

Can I install downloaded *.apk silently?

Comment: Why would you want to install stuff without the user knowing?

Comment: I think this question has been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android

Comment: I need it to let my main app to install & update child apps.

Comment: I don`t need any notifications to user.

Comment: re: why? Android devices aren't limited to phones. Consider media appliances or other network devices that have tacit consent from the user to "just work" (that is, auto-update).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I`ve found the issue.

1. Added "`android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES`" permission.
2. I signed my application using "`signapk.jar`" with certificate that I`ve got from manufacturer of my device.
3. And now this app can install others using "`pm install /.../app.apk`" without "su".

It works!

P.S. **Updating application** using just "pm install" doesn`t replace existing application with new one, but returns exit_value = 0. So to update there are two ways:

- use "`pm install -r /.../app.apk`";
- firstly delete app using "`pm uninstall com.mydomain.myapp`" (you need "`android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES`" permission) and then install new one.

Comment: How to upgrade itself? I have an apk which has auto-update functions. But it put in /system/app, now only pm install seems not work.

Comment: @3c71, this update command will update APK accordingly to versions? (I mean update will process only if we update with newer version?)

Comment: Not sure actually. I was expecting -r to replace the existing app with whatever the APK is, be it the same version, newer or older. While the pm install would only replace if version is newer, not the same.

Comment: @yuralife I am not sure on this are u able to install apk without rooting?

Comment: @yuralife Ok. While you are at it..can you also explain how do you install a System app on device..I am on the same lines but unable to figure out. Thanks

Comment: @yuralife can you please eplain how to contact the manufacturers?

Comment: Work like a charm with the manufacturer certificate!! Thanks!!

Comment: Hello,
how do I get the "certficate manufacturer" of my device?

Comment: What will happen if app is currently playing and you try to run the update? Will it restart,crash or something else?
Another question... Is this code in app we are trying to update or in some other app which will update mine?

Comment: @NixSam 1. App will closed without any crash; 2. You can not update the app by itself, that code should be executed in another app.

Comment: @yuralife thanks for quick response. I tried it, but I have some problems executing any command. I tried just executing pwd command and I got Error running exec(). Command: [pwd] Working Directory: null Environment: null. No matter what I do, I got Working Directory: null Environment: null. It is a rooted emulator, I've checked it. 
I have write permission in manifest. 
Do you know maybe where is a problem? I lost bunch of hours to figure it out, don't know what it could be.

Comment: @NixSam you should try that on real device, because as I know sometimes emulator can have different behavior especially at such specific tests.

Comment: how do I get the "certficate manufacturer" of my device? please explain the way ?

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot. Simply having the same UID isn't enough. You must also be signed with the same key as the ROM itself.

Silently installing apps, or updates to your own app, isn't allowed for security reasons.

Comment: But my app is signed with certificate that I`ve got from manufacturer. This app will run only on ONE type and model of device.

Comment: @yuralife In such a case, the manufacturer should build your app into the system image, where it can be autoupdates with other preinstalled apps.

Comment: Ok, but this built-in main-app should be able to install simple apps without user confirmation. And I don`t know how to implement this?

Comment: @yuralife You don't need to. It is the manufacturers responsibility. Your app will update the same way as Gmail etc.

Comment: But I need to control this updating and its not a market app. For example, before updating I need to check if it`s not using by user.

Comment: @yuralife You can't install updates, market or otherwise, silently unless your app is in the system partition, where it can be put only by the OEM. Once there, you can use terminal commands to copy your app. However, this will have to be done through another proxy app, as  your own process will be killed during the copy process if you overwrite your own app, stopping the update in the middle. OEMs usually have such proxy apps.

Comment: One way - copy my app I need to install/update to /data/app and it`s possible to system-level app?

Comment: data/app is normall apps. System apps are in system/app

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26886/discussion-between-yuralife-and-raghav-sood)

Answer (score 0):

In order to autoupdate your app silently, you have 2 options.

1. Sign your app with the manufacturer certificate.
2. Put your app under /system/priv-app folder. Putting an apk under /system/ folder makes the app a system app, but it is not enough for it to autoupdate.
   During the autoupdate process, it will not throw any error, but autoupdate will fail.
   If the apk is under /system/priv-app folder or one of its subfolders, autoupdate will complete successfully.

Use PackageInstaller class for autoupdate.

```
 private boolean installPackage(Context context, String packageName, String apkPath) throws IOException {
    File f = new File(apkPath);
    if(!f.exists()){
        Log.i(TAG, "[installPackage] Apk file cannot be updated because file is not available. apkPath:"+apkPath);
        return false;
    }

    FileInputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    PackageInstaller.Session session = null;
    int sessionId = 0;
    try{
        PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
        PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
        params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
        // set params
        sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
        session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);

        // Copy APK file bytes into OutputStream provided by install Session
        out = session.openWrite(packageName, 0, -1);
        in = new FileInputStream(f);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, c);
        }
        out.flush();

        session.fsync(out);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "[installPackage] apkPath:"+apkPath+", error:", e);
        return false;
    }finally {
        StreamUtil.closeSilently(out, in);
        out = null;
        in = null;
        System.gc();
    }

    try{
        // The app gets killed after installation session commit
        session.commit(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, sessionId, new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"), getPendingIntentFlag(0)).getIntentSender());
        session.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "[installPackage] session commit error:", e);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
public int getPendingIntentFlag(int flag){
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ? (PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | flag) : flag;
}
```