# Install Apk Silently in Android programatically without ROOT

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to install app silently in android without using user prompt and without ROOT.

I know this question has lots of answers but i can't find proper answer for same.

i.e  is it possible if we make app as device admin or device owner or profile owner ?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silent install apk programmatically by system app (without root)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619693/silent-install-apk-programmatically-by-system-app-without-root)

Comment: that is impossible and has to stay impossible.

Comment: @NicoHaase i tried but not worked

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, the only way for skip user prompt, is to be root and place the apk on the system folder instead of app folder

If the apk is in the system folder you can install it silently easely, but the system folder can only be access with ROOT

Comment: Not to mention the **huge**, obvious security implications this would raise if this was indeed possible.

Comment: @MichaelDodd Is it possible if we make app as device admin or device owner or profile owner ?

Comment: @MohitTrivedi Nope, only if the device has been rooted by the user, as Vodet mentioned in their answer. Otherwise the system partition will remain read-only.