# Installing apk within PhoneGap/Sencha Touch app

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

How can I provide an update feature in my Sencha Touch and Phonegap app? I want to have an update button that will download the latest apk from server and replace my old apk. I don't have a clue. Can anybody suggest me something?

Answer (score 2):

Could you not just submit you app to a store like [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store?hl=en_GB) and let it manage updates for you?

Edit:

Alternatively try this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15932364/171144) to the question [Phonegap Android app trigger update programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880866/phonegap-android-app-trigger-update-programmatically/15932364#15932364).

Or this [blog post on using the Install Intent in Phonegap 3.0](https://coderwall.com/p/lraraa).

Comment: no i am not using google play to download app. Its a CRM app for a company . The updated apk will be on their own web server so the app should update from there only .