# Android: install .apk programmatically with Ionic - Cordova - Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, installation, ionic-framework

The question is simple, is there a way to install an apk from an app developed with Ionic, Cordova or Phonegap ?
I've read the answer to install "install .apk programmatically" using Java, as a native app.

I've looked a lot for this, thanks.

Comment: "cordova run android"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest these:

https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent

[Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

[Install Application programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android)

[Phonegap Android app trigger update programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880866/phonegap-android-app-trigger-update-programmatically)

Comment: The last link is a good aproximation about what im looking for, thanks a lot mr Mohammad.