# Update app on user request - android

Tags: android, updates

Is it possible for updates not to be pushed to all devices, but only requested by the device when a certain point is reached within the application? (Ideally using Google play, but not necessarily)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about google play. But you can think about this.

After reaching the specific point check your server for update . if there is any new update then dowload the updated apk file. Then you can install the new apk.

To install the apk you can see this answers

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969421/931982), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604922/931982)

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might be how I was going to have to do it.