# How to programmatically install an APK from a Service

Tags: android, installation, apk

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

This was found here:
[Question [4967669] android-install-apk-programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

Using an android **Service** if do this I get the following error message:

> 05-03 08:24:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   Thread-1706 05-03 08:24:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(21288):
>   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from
>   outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   flag. Is this really what you want?

I added the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

But now nothing happens. No error but also no attempt to install the apk. 
I am thinking it might be because it has no activity (since it is a service)?

**QUESTION**
Is it possible to install an APK via android background service? (if so) does any one knwo how do I do it?

Thanks in Advance

*PS: From my understanding of services they are very much like activities so not sure why this wont work.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android. Check the accepted answer in the link

Comment: can u help me from which Link or resources u have taken help i am newbie and facing difficulty to achieve same target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install an APK from a background service.
Try to use `Uri.parse` instead of `Uri.fromFile`

```
        File apkfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                  "/download/" + "app.apk");
        if (!apkfile.exists()) {
            return;
        }
        Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        installIntent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file://" + apkfile.toString()),
                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(installIntent);
```

Comment: it does work from an service. My APK was actually corrupted and was showing a parsing message which was being hidden by an activity. Thanks.