# Accessing/Upgrading/Clearing Mobile Devices: MDM

Tags: android, ios, mobile, mdm

We are building an enterprise focused mobile application.

To take this app to the market we need to figure out how to remotely
a) upgrade / wipe the application on mobile devices
b) get access to the device for support and troubleshooting

I guess mobile device management (MDM) applications like AirWatch or
MobiControl can do this job. But they are expensive and do a lot of
other things which we are not interested in.

Is there anything else in the market that is especially geared for
mobile application developers to add the above features within their
application?

*Addition:
We are working on iOS and Android for now.

Comment: you forgot to mention which operation system are you talking about - iOS, Android, WP, Blackberry 10?

Comment: Hi- thanks, it will be iOS and Android for now: I'll also update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS

**Install/Upgrade**

On iOS you can use MDM API to install and upgrade apps. However, there are multiple gotchas

- A user has to accept it
- If the same app is preinstalled by user, you won't be able to install it/upgrade it through MDM

**Wipe**

You can wipe only whole device or you can remove an application which will remove it's data. However, you can remove only apps which was installed through MDM

**Get access to the device for support and troubleshooting**

If you are talking about remote desktop like capabilities then you are out of luck. You can't remotely control it. However, you may be interested to look at airplay mirroring.

## Android

**Install/Upgrade**

Look at this: [Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)
[Install Application programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android)

**Wipe**

You can use device admin capabilities for this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

**Get access to the device for support and troubleshooting**

I am not sure.

**Obvious self-marketing :)**

Can you contact me by email (I have it in my profile). My company does a lot of things which you are interested it. May be we can find interesting opportunity for a cooperation.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for this. The application that we are building uses HTML 5.0 technology, are there any APIs relevant to this?

Comment: Is this completely web app (meaning no binary installed on mobile devices)? In such case, all upgrades happens on the server side, wipe happens on the server side too. However, as soon as you have binaries, my answer is applicable.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, we've developed a completely web based app and I think we are moving towards an off the shelf product to do this for us.