# Auto-update solutions other than Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play, auto-update, software-distribution

I have a private application that will be installed in about 500 to 1000 phones. I'm concerned about how I'm going to update all of those. I don't want to list it on Google Play (since it's a private app). I've also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274076/android-autoupdate-from-own-server) but it involves me firing up a server for this.

Is there any online alternative that I can send my updates to and they distribute it to my devices?

Comment: you can upload your app as "Beta" on Google Play and then create a community of your "private users" who would be able to find and download the app to their devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely agree with Katharina's reply. I just want to explain in more detail about HockeyApp.

[HockeyApp](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/general-account-management-2/general-questions#what-is-hockeyapp-) is a platform used to test apps for developers. Every account automatically comes with our free plan, which offers unlimited distribution, crash reporting, and feedback for 2 apps – allowing you to get started and explore without any monetary commitment.

The most important step is to integrate a HA SDK speficied for your platform, for your case, it should be Android https://rink.io/sEptDQM. Then you could benefit from following HA features:

- Distribute Builds
- Invite Testers
- Collect crash reports
- Show update alerts for new beta builds
- Add a feedback view directly into your app
- User metric data and statistic data analysis
- More more....

If you have any questions, please contact us at support@hockeyapp.net

Comment: The links seem not to work anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Try Hockeyapp: https://www.hockeyapp.net/features/

It's free for 2 apps.

Comment: This seems not accessible anymore!