# Android Install apk from url

Tags: java, android, http, download

I have an android app which is check is there any updates are available. If I have a new version number, the program should open a link and install an apk:

This would be a link:

http://sample.com/sample.apk

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android), it might help you out.

Comment: Ive tired that but doesnt work I have just could download the file, but I need to install programatically

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater still it will ask user to install it ... there is no way to do this without user interaction on non rooted devices

Comment: What doesn't work? If you downloaded the file and you know where it is stored, you can follow the procedure explained in that question, right?

Comment: Cause this example for local apk. But I need from external server

Comment: So then Why it open a webbrowser I would like to just download and ofcourse with user permission install the apk