# Do not show installation procedure on the screen

Tags: android, user-interface, installation

I have an application and I want it to install another application, but I do not want this procedure be shown on the screen or requested the user. Is there any way to do this?

**"An application go install another"**

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Actually, this application is for android tablets

Comment: Then, you should include an android tag into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Thankfully not. This would be a horrible security problem. Applications can [install other applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android), but not silently.