# Android app update automatic and silently?

Tags: android, root

I develop an app and want update itself and want following fetures, device have been rooted :

1 automatic check can update every start (I can do)
 2 download the apk file to local (I can do)
 3 update with custom dialog, or update silently (I dont know )

edit：
My app run on TV with remote, the default dialog which can control but perfect , so I want use my dialog if there must a dialog.Its best if need not a dialog.

Answer (score 2):

First declare this variables, then call function wherever you want. Then grant superuser, on your superuser application, check the option to always grant, for non user interaction.

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
            //some code...
             final String libs = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib ";

             final String commands = libs + "pm install -r " + "your apk directory"+ "app.apk";

             instalarApk(commands); 
 }

   private void instalarApk( String commands ) {
    try {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su" );
        InputStream es = p.getErrorStream();
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

        os.writeBytes(commands + "\n");

        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();

        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        String output = new String();
        while ((read = es.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output += new String(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        p.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(Debug.TAG, e.toString());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.v(Debug.TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post :)

Answer (score 0):

The regular way (without root and a default installer dialog) is described [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android), and should be used in most cases imho, as I dislike requesting root privileges for a update feature.

There is no difference in providing a custom dialog and installing an apk silently, as both technically are silent installs (e.g. not made by the install activity). With root privileges, you could use a root shell and either replace the apk ([as in the open-source keybord manager app](https://bitbucket.org/ne0fhyk/keyboard-manager/src/2c327c89dd8698a48d499a0dd2e3ea266b3a9e7e/KmLauncher/src/com/ne0fhykLabs/android/utility/kmLauncher/Launcher.java?at=default#cl-283)) or invoke the [package manager](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/05/android-shell-command-pm-package-manager.html) from shell. I'd suggest you go for the second way, I linked the keybord manager app source mainly for the root shell creation stuff.

Answer (score -2):

The Android Framework make it defficult to update silently, on custom devices you must call system install service for your apk file, and it will show the install dialog for the user, but if the device is rooted, I think you can make that silently.