# Application Management in wso2 emm

Tags: android-package-managers, wso2-iot

I'm testing the implementation of the emm, and as i understood in the documentation i can

- Automatically install applications WITHOUT end user intervention
- Block any application to prevent its installation
- Automatically UNINSTALL any app without end user intervention

I tried to perform this tasks using Policies but it didn't seem to work.

I'll appreciate your help.

Thanks.
Gabriel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure WSO2 EMM in order to get it working. However for Android devices silent installation and uninstallation does not work until you install the Android Agent app as a system app in your devices. So it will prompt a message to user when EMM server perform an installation or uninstallation operation on the device. But for iOS it happens without use intervention.

if you blocking an app, EMM 1.0.0 shows an warning message to the android users to remove it. and for iOS it actually block the app.

You can use policies to block apps and install apps to the devices.

For iOS you need to configure it according to the documentation in order to get it working. For Android it works without any configurations, but if you are going for production you need to configure it.

Comment: I've tried to copy the Android Agent into the /system/app directory of the device but it still shows the

Comment: did you able to copy it? you need to have a root access for that.

Comment: I've created an "Enforced" policy to force the installation of a particular application. I've copied the Android Agent into the /system/app directory of the device but it still prompts a confirmation message to the user. DO i need to configure something into the agent code ?

Thanks.
Gabriel.

Comment: You have to modify the code for that. how to do that is mentioned in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583563/android-app-update-automatic-and-silently

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue by rooting the Android devices we're using and installing the Xposed Framework, along with the XInstaller module for it. There are several options for installation/uninstallation that can be used to create an installation/uninstallation experience free from the need for user intervention.

This was pretty easy for me to do, as we're only using corporate-owned devices that don't even leave the facility. Your mileage may vary.