# Apk File download Error using Java in Android

Tags: java, android, android-install-apk

.I followed this tutorial and getting errors **"PARSING ERROR THERE IS A PROBLEM PARSING THE PACKAGE"**. I have check the result in Android Device Samsung Galaxy S3.

```
    package com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.activities;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.URL;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.Environment;
        import android.util.Log;


        public class ApkFileAsync extends Activity
        {
            UpdateApp updateAppInstance;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedBundleInstance)
        {

        super.onCreate(savedBundleInstance);
        updateAppInstance = new UpdateApp();
        updateAppInstance.setContext(getApplicationContext());
        updateAppInstance.execute("http://demo.ingresssolutions.com/proposalmanagement/services/user/getApkFile");
        }

        private class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
        private Context context;
        public void setContext(Context contextf){
            context = contextf;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
              try {
                    URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
                    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    c.setDoOutput(true);
                    c.connect();

                    String PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/Download/";
                    File file = new File(PATH);
                    file.mkdirs();
                    File outputFile = new File(file,"surveyapp.apk");
                    if(outputFile.exists()){
                        outputFile.delete();
                    }
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                    InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len1 = 0;
                    while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    }
                    fos.close();
                    is.close();

                  /*  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/update.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);*/ // without this flag android returned a intent error!
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);  
                    context.startActivity(intent);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("UpdateAPP", "Update error! " + e.getMessage());
                }
            return null;
 }}  
  }
```

I am getting this error after `Complete Action using` dialog when trying to press either `PACKAGE INSTALLER` or `VERIFY AND INSTALL` in both cases same error.
[image: Manifest file]

Comment: Must check your app package name

Comment: once Check your manifest file like package name,application name and also check your android package name generated Packagename..

Comment: @Madhu i am newbie can u please elaborate this line i have checked in manifest file  and also check your android package name generated Packagename.

Comment: this is Manifest File: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mrfs.android.surveyapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" ><uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
android:name="WorkflowApp"android:allowBackup="true"

Comment: have added snapshot of manifest file

Comment: hey how many packages you are using.. in your app

Comment: 9  packages i am using

Comment: which version of android your device run on?

Comment: 4.1.2 version of android device

Comment: @ErumHannan try changing your `minSdkVersion` to `15`

Comment: i guess there is some problem of app name and package name

Comment: @ErumHannan yes, you have to provide the package name `where your launch activity is located`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45367/discussion-between-erum-hannan-and-r9j)

Comment: hey Erum Hannan you are getting this error while installing i think.. If so There is proble with code and package name.. and also set ur min sdk levelas 15 or 14.. it wil work.. because android s3 has ICS..

Comment: What is the device version you are using now to install your app..?

Comment: why don't you use `Uri.fromFile(outputFile)` in the intent, and why don'y you use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` in PATH ?

Comment: have you created **activities** folder in ur app?

Comment: @njzk2 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "surveyapp.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

Comment: my point is more like `why do you define twice the same thing, with different methods and the risk that on some devices it may not work?`

Answer (score 0):

Change your manifes to like

[image]

This should work fine i think.. If not worked please post your tutorial link i missed it.. i need to check it.. and i will update answer...
and also mention how you are installing app wether by eclipse or by some other process like importing apk... IF importing apk to real device means please check ur device version, If its s3 mans it has ICS api level includes 14 or 15 so change that.. if its jellly bean means you can use up to 18

Comment: link i have followed 2nd Anser:  For ICS I´ve implemented your code and made a class that extends AsyncTaskhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically?rq=1

Comment: k so you want  install .apk programmatically so use juro question and answer of that link its worked fine i tried it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android   there is problep with your code that code works for only few devices.. which will include root permissions also.. so follow juros answer..

Comment: following JUROS answer lets see result

Comment: hey Erum Hannan Can you send me Code to this email justdoit1str@gmail.com.. so that i will check that.. before sending Remove all your personal belongings.. regarding that application.. and send me example code.. I think the problem is that your device require root permissions.. so once send me i will check it...

Comment: can u please let me know your skype id so that i can let u know project flow becoz my project contains so many code

Comment: have u recieved any file in your email ?

Comment: Hey Erum Hannan i am in office Skype youtube temveawer not works so  send your code to email.. my laptop is protected by server so i cant install any skype or temveawer so but softwares are preloaded so i can see problem... sorry for late responce i am in week off..