# How to Decode a URL using Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, parsing

I am newbie in android, i have this url now i need to encode this url: [the url that has to be encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159636/apk-file-download-error-using-java-in-android?noredirect=1#comment31854159_21159636).
With Reference of downloading apk in Mobile using Java how can i pass this url to this Line :

```
updateAppInstance.execute("http://demo.ingresssolutions.com/proposalmanagement/services/user/getApkFile");
```

[Previous post Regarding Apk Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159636/apk-file-download-error-using-java-in-android?noredirect=1#comment31854159_21159636)

http://demo.ingresssolutions.com/proposalmanagement/services/user/uploadFile

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to many answers you will read, java.net.URLEncoder isn't for encoding URLs. It is for encoding URL and POST *arguments.*

The correct way to encode a URL in Java is as given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962879/207421), or, if you only need to encode the path component:

```
String encodedPath = new URI(null, path, null).toASCIIString();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.net.URL; 
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.MalformedURLException; 
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Encoder{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  URL url = null; 
  try{
   url = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com");       
  }catch(MalformedURLException mue){
   System.err.println(mue); 
  }
  System.out.println(url + "
"); 
  try{
   String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(url.toString(),"UTF-8"); 
   System.out.println(encodedurl);
  }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee){
   System.err.println(uee);
  }
 }
}
```

Hope this helps you