# What is appropriate way to install group of applications programmatically?

Tags: android

In my application I need to install group of another applications. My idea is install them one by one in such a way:

1) Install first application
2) In `onResume` check if there are applications to install. If yes, install current application and go to 2 again.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way looks good. But you need the user interaction for every installation, if the device is not rooted. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604922/1515052).