# How to programmatically access installer service in android?

Tags: java, android, installation, apk

I have struck an idea of creating an app that automatically installs all the .apk packages placed inside a particular folder. In context to this, I want to learn how do I programmatically access installer service ?

Please enlighten me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to set an intent with type **application/vnd.android.package-archive** and then start installer activity:

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your.apk"), 
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

Check out [Install Application programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android)

Also, note, that for security reasons, you cannot install an apk 'silently' or automatically without user agreement. Therefore, the best you can do is like above.