# Install app programmatically without openning play store

Tags: android

this question has already been asked here [How to install applications programmatically without opening Play Store (as Google Drive does)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695170/how-to-install-applications-programmatically-without-opening-play-store-as-googl) but I want to know how it works

I am supposed to write this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE");
intent.setClassName("com.android.vending","com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.LightPurchaseFlowActivity");
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, EXTRA_VALUE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

So what should be in this line: intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, EXTRA_VALUE);

and how it's getting another app without opening play store

Comment: If you read the answer from which you pulled this code, you will find that it has: "However, calling LightPurchaseFlowActivity from non-Google signed app is failing, because they are, again apparently (according to the logs), checking the calling package's signature... this can not be achieved at this moment".

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it cant be done, only google signed app can do it.