# Download & Install apk from google play store without visiting play store

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I am having an ImageView,on click of that I want to download an apk from google play store ,without passing intent to google play store.You can see the code below which I am implementing right now but it is opening play store.I want to download whatsapp on click of the image. Please Guide.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse
                        ("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "com.whatsapp")));
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can not download apk direct although you can redirect the user to installing page.

Comment: then put apk file in your own server and upon image click using web service and download manager download the apk but its not possible from  google play store i guess.

Comment: It is working in my airtel app

Comment: airtel have own server for this you can say own playstore

Comment: Can we do this or not?

Comment: from PlayStore??Nope.

Comment: If I am having my own server at play store than?

Comment: If you have your own server and the apk on the server you can download it.

Comment: How?Can u plz explain

Comment: Plz tell me the code.

Answer (score 1):

check it... but you can't install directly without click on install button

[Related topic 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android)

[Related topic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695170/how-to-install-applications-programatically-without-opening-play-store-as-googl)

Comment: I want like my airtel app

Comment: i don't think it's possible do some google maybe you get something new...

Comment: I have already done google,but not able to find  satisfactory solution to my question

Comment: coz it's not possible. if u have you own server you can download and install... firstly check above links

Comment: If I am having my own server than?How to do this?

Comment: then set the url link or webservice to download .apk file after download it's install automatically like playstore

Comment: If i use the same code then it open a google play store.

Comment: @Shivangi  sorry just do google how to make a webservice and all

Comment: ya it open the playstore on whatsapp page

Comment: for more info. you just check the links which i mention in answer

Comment: Okey, i am doing google,but not getting result.Anyways thnx

Comment: welcome @Shivangi if you got some imp. info. please give a imp. flag or upvote