# installing android app from notification bar

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-notifications

According to my app concept we are not submitting the app in play store.

Whenever the user launches the app, it checks for the latest update through a web service. If there is a latest apk available in server it will be downloaded to a particular path in sd card. The downloading process is shown in the notification bar. Here comes my problem.

```
After download is completed, the notification is shown in Notification bar as "App is completed downloading" with app icon. Now when the user touches the my apps notification i want it to be either installed or need to open the sd card path. How to implement this process
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Application programmatically on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
     Intent install_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     install_intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myapp.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
     PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(YourAcrtivity.this,0, install_intent, 0);
     notification.setContentIntent(pending);
```

Comment: @SivaK When your download complete. How did you downloaded file?

Comment: what if the  download  happens  for the  first time ? before the the  current  app is  already there  ?