# Auto install Android App after copying to SDCard

Tags: android

I know this is may or may not be possible,but I just want to confirm is it possible in android or not?

So here it goes,Let's say I have an android app ( example my_app.apk) ,I copied my_app.apk from my computer or through pendrive or downloaded from website to my android device( let's say I copied to /sdcard/).***I have also activated install app from unknown sources in my phone settings***.

Now is there any way through which I can make the App to auto install on the device as soon as I copied to /sdcard folder? I mean my_app.apk should kick auto installation on the device without user navigating to /sdcard of the device and selecting the app and clicking the install option.

I just want to know is this possible in Android? if Yes how can I achieve that? I don't want to use other third party applications to kick off installation,instead the app should kick installation itself as soon as it gets copied to /sdcard folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible. It is possible to have Android app which checks some folders and detects new file and [automatically install new apk files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android). To install apk package ordinary (from SD card) you should activated installing from Unknown sources in settings. Auto instalation packages aren't possible, because it could be security problem.