# Is there any way to add activity to app(apk) which is already delivered to customer

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android application,already live on playstore, but due to certain changes in the requirement, I have to add one more activity to the app without updating the app again on playstore.

Also for future projects, how can I make the application update some part of its code, or patch a broken code without updating the app on the store.

In advance thank you!!

Comment: Why do want to defeat the system (store) that already helps you do just that: deliver patches to customers?

Comment: We have around 200-250 template apps for restaurants and updating each on play store is tedious for us.So we were finding a way to do that

Comment: Maybe you aren't asking the proper question. Perhaps, what you want is just a downloadable xml (or a csv or a SharedPreference file or whatever) template (or a resultset from a database query). Something to customize your customer's logo, colors, ...

Comment: Not only ui but i also want to change the functionality( which is written in java class) of live app how can i do any help!!!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that, unless your app is explicitly designed and written to support i.e. dynamic UI based on your external resoiurces/files etc. This is not the case so answer is "no".

> or patch a broken code without updating the app on the store

You can download APK from external source and [init its installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android).

Comment: Hey Marcin Orlowski can you guide me something about how to patch a broken code for app.