# java.lang.SecurityException Not allowed to install apk from another android application

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app in which I am trying to download from a location(a website) an apk, store it on the sd card and I want to install it on my device.

However, I encounter the following error when trying to install the apk:
java.lang.SecurityException: Caller is not allowed to install APKs

Any suggestions on why the exception appears?

For installing I do the following:

```
public static void installApk(ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(APK_KEY, APK_NAME);
    values.put(PACKAGE_KEY, PACKAGE_NAME);
    values.put(APKS_DIR_PATH_KEY, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + APKS_DIR_PATH + APK_NAME);
    try {
        contentResolver.insert(INSTALL_SINGLE_URI, values);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        //permission not granted
        Log.e(Utils.class.getSimpleName(), e.toString());
    }   }
```

Comment: maybe your app needs root access.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions">

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android

Comment: One other issue is that I am using a third party app to install the apk, so I don't really know how to find out if that permission is set in the manifest file of the third party app.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you must add this to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

But now the hard one comes. If you want to install packages from your app, you have to install your app to /system/app. Only in this case INSTALL_PACKAGES permission works. Other easy way, just call the url of apk and let system default package manager to handle the job :)

Comment: One other issue is that I am using a third party app to install the apk, so I don't really know how to find out if that permission is set in the manifest file of the third party app.

Comment: You can see that app's manifest file and even change it with a basic uncompression app like 7z. But there is too much workaround and not nice :)