# Android Install app dialog

Tags: java, android

I have a pretty simple question but somehow not able to find a solution on stackoverflow.

I am able to start the downloading of file from `WebView` and also able to listen to `Broadcast` after download completes. Here is the relevant code

```
aWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                        long contentLength) {
//              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//              i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
//              startActivity(i);

                final String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype);

                        Request request = new Request(
                            Uri.parse(url));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName); 
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);  
            }
        });
```

Now what I need to know is, any way we can popup the app `Install/Cancel` dialog programmatically for that particular downloaded app ?

Comment: look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
String filePath = "Your file path";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

The situation is something special as you use for the .apk file downloaded from your app?