# Install/Update APK files from local server automatically

Tags: android, windows, google-play

I'm developing an corporative application , this application would be installed/updated in more than 100 devices.
I would know if exist a way to set up a local (windows) server and connect all the devices to this server to update the application automatically via wifi/mobile network (something like a google play, but local)

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in checking for, download, and request install update for a custom app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android

Comment: Private channel will be useful. I'm assuming users only have android devices https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2623322?hl=en  and https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en