# java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: Working Directory: null Environment: null

Tags: android, ioexception, android-install-apk, silent-installer

I'am trying to install apk silently without any prompt.

This is the code which installs the apk file by using adb command.

```
public void InstallAPK(String filename){
    File file = new File(filename);
    if(file.exists()){
        try {
            String command;
            command = "adb install -r " + filename;
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command });
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run this code, I am getting the following error.

> java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su, -c, adb install -r /storage/emulated/0/Download/sampleapp.apk] Working Directory: null Environment: null

I have given these permissions.

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

Please can someone help me to solve this error.

Comment: could you find a solution for this? If so, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can't silently run a command in an application's scope to install an apk outside that application's scope.

But you can rise an intent to make AOSP do that. Check this answer maybe: [Install Application programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android)

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
     .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your.apk"), 
                     "application/vnd.android.package-archive");   
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this already. But I am trying to install without prompt.

Comment: Not possible for any phone. You can root your own phone and make it happen but you don't want that.