# Install my second application from my first application

Tags: android

I have my two applications, I want to install my second application from my first application but without using playstore.
When I will click on an button from my first app, Second app should install there only else if it is installed then it should open by getting some information form first app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4604922/6316670
This might help

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Problem is - My second app is on playstore but I dont want to switch user on play store for installation. I need to install it from my first app screen only.