# Update app without Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-install-apk

I have one service where I can put new apk file.For example, (https://myweb.com/newversion.apk).My project is not in play store and I would to update my app remote,without play store.
I search about this in google,found some examples and articles,but I don't know witch is a best practice to solve my problem
In your option,how I can solve my problem most optimal way?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One of the most optimal ways is to store APP version somewhere in web (for example in JSON file)  with your APK file. And when running your app check if app version is not lower than stored in web JSON. If current app version is lower than stored in web - download new APK in background and and prompt user with notification and dialog about successful download and offer him to launch installation. For more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android) threads.

Answer (score 1):

To implement auto update you can manage with your server with version details but for that you have to checked with application as well.

But there are another option from where you can manage auto-update.
You can use custom class provide by below URL.

```
http://www.auto-update-apk.com/
```