# Opening another app

Tags: java, android

How can i open APK file recently downloaded from my application?

I tried:

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivity(it);
```

But this didn't work at all it wanted to open it by PDF reader.

```
public void install(File file){
    if(file.exists()){
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(i);}
}
```

With this code i have package error while opening this app.

Comment: Already asked here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android)

Comment: String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/download";
        Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .setDataAndType(Uri.parse(sdcard),
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(promptInstall);}

this is crashing.

Comment: The app must be installed, in order to be opened.

Comment: I want to open apk file in order to let user install it

Answer (score 0):

I think your code will run only **< N**.

For that you have to implement [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html),

Comment: how can i do this to apk ? I can't do this i want to open file from my apk folder/download ?