# how to download apk and install on android 6

Tags: java, android

How to download and install an apk file in Android programming. We have problems with Android 6 and above.

```
dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(file_url));
enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
    receiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                        DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = c
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                            .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                        String uriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE));
                        String uriString2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_URI));

                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent2.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(uriString2)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    StartActivity.this.registerReceiver(receiver3, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

when **download finish** and install `error:parse` error there was a problem parsing the `package` stack

Comment: any screenshot can you show related to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
>     DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(file_url));
>     enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
>         receiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
>             @Override
>             public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>                 String action = intent.getAction();
>                 if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
>                     long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
>                             DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
>                     DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
>                     query.setFilterById(enqueue);
>                     Cursor c = dm.query(query);
>                     if (c.moveToFirst()) {
>                         int columnIndex = c
>                                 .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
>                         if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
>                                 .getInt(columnIndex)) {
>
>                             String uriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE));
>                             String uriString2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_URI));
>
>                            File file = new File(dir, "App.apk");
> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
> intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
> startActivity(intent);
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         };
>         StartActivity.this.registerReceiver(receiver3, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
> ```

Comment: what is dir on "File file = new File(dir, "App.apk");"

Comment: "File file = new File(uriString2)"

Comment: no , not workin i have error when startactivity(intent) to install. my error parse error there was a problem parsing the package

Answer (score 0):

May be this link can be useful for you

```
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android
```

Along with check the following factor that affect installation.

File may be downloaded incompletely.
Application might not be suitable for your device config.
Security issue -  but you can enable from setting option.
Corrupted APK file.

Comment: no on android 6 have error parse error there was a problem parsing the package