# Installing apk programatically causing parse error

Tags: android

I am trying to install an apk programmatically.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AppFolder/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

This is the code I have used. But when I run the code it prompts to choose package installer and when I select package installer I am getting the error  `"There was a problem while parsing the package"`.

This is my MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnInstall;
private String path;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24){
        try{
            Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
            m.invoke(null);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    btnInstall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btnInstall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "Snapseed.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Am trying to install Snapseed app from the SDcard by clicking the button`

Thanks in advance.

Solved :
Thank you all.I have found the issue. I was saving the file in my External storage but in the code, I was pointing to internal storage.

Comment: Please check that your apk has the minimum sdk version which is greater than the device version (API level) you are trying to install and let me know

Comment: I am able to install the app maually.But when i try programatically am getting the error

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same APK when installing manually. There can be the reason if the App shows "Parse Error" when the file is corrupted.

Comment: Checkout [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604922/6611700)

Comment: Yes am using the same apk

Comment: you can add this permission on your manifest file : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
?

Comment: @EbyCloudins Could you identify the issue now ?

Answer (score 1):

Add Flag in your code. Try this one. It works for me.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File
 (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "Xender.apk")),
 "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Check this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cjt5ObW_Yxw @EbyCloudins

Comment: In this its not installing when tried manually. But for me when i install the apk manually its installing properly but i try to install using the app am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error in my case.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/app-debug.apk";

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

We've to check the label of existing and the new `.apk` should be same.

Hope this will help.

**Edit**

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive" );
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    Log.d("Lofting", "About to install new .apk");
    startActivity(i);
```

The above code is working fine for me, I can install or update my existing app.

Comment: labels are same

Comment: I think, you should look into the path. try adding `getAbsolutePath()`. Please check, the apk name, the default is `app-debug.apk` or `app-release.apk` for the signed one. Is this `Snapseed.apk` after generating the .apk?

Comment: i don't think, it need here. I was getting `parsing error` because of name of `apk`. I had changed the app name as `Lavazza.apk` and the app was generated as `app-debug.apk`. Is these same in your case?

Comment: First i renamed it. But now am using it as app-debug.apk

Comment: Well, this is the issue. Try uninstalling the previous one. Install the app without changing the name and then use the program of installation.

Comment: The app is not installed now, i need to install it only using program

Comment: now am using the app-debug apk. I have not renamed it

Comment: Even then it's getting the name `Snapseed.apk`, I believe. First time try installing manually with the label `app-debug.apk`. And then the program will work.

Comment: I am able to install it maually. But not using program

Comment: Have you tried manually after changing the name from `Snapseed` to `app-debug` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165535/discussion-between-eby-cloudins-and-shambhu).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

add permission on **Manifest** file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

and try this code for installing apk

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent();
newIntent.putExtra(PackageUtil.INTENT_ATTR_APPLICATION_INFO, 
mPkgInfo.applicationInfo);
newIntent.setData(mPackageURI);
newIntent.setClass(this, InstallAppProgress.class);
String installerPackageName = 
getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME);
if (installerPackageName != null) {
    newIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME, 
    installerPackageName);
}
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Comment: this permission can be granted to only system apps