# Android app uninstall in android 7 programmatically

Tags: android, android-launcher, kiosk-mode

I want to uninstall android app without user prompting in android 7 rooted device.I tried below code.

```
 try {
            Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

            outputStream.writeBytes("pm uninstall " + packageName + "\n");
            outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
            outputStream.flush();
            su.waitFor();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }
```

It's working fine in android 6.But version 7,we can't execute su command.

please anyone know any method to do this without user prompting,share with me that code.

or tell me can we execute **adb uninstall packageName** likewise

Comment: can anyone help me??

Comment: I think This link Help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android

Comment: @Mac New,I can't use it,because it will prompting.What I want is,I want to uninstall app without user knowing.