# How to install .apk into android device programatically?

Tags: android, installation, android-uiautomator

Can anyone help in how to install .apk file in the android device/emulator programmatically?

I have tried the below methods:

```
UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
mDevice.executeShellCommand("adb shell pm install -t -r /data/local/tmp/com.example.xxxxx.xxxxxx");
```

But it is not working.

I am using UIAutomator for android native app automation testing, I need to install .apk file into android device/emulator before proceeding with my test scripts execution.

Comment: any error messages? and can not see .apk file name in your codes.

Comment: I have used like this ,  mDevice.executeShellCommand("adb install -t -r /Users/xxxx/Desktop/app-debug.apk");, Also tried with package name as i mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executeShellCommand` runs inside your device. No need `adb shell` again.

```
UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
mDevice.executeShellCommand("pm install -t -r /data/local/tmp/com.example.xxxxx.xxxxxx");
```

Comment: Thanks Rilwan, It is working. I have removed adb shell and tried. But before executing this i have pused .apk file to android device manually and then I have tried with above code. Can you please help me in how to execute adb push command through code to push my .apk file in my system to android device. I have tried with "Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);" But getting this error "Permission denied error -13"

Comment: Good it worked! The execShell is executing inside your phone. You cannot invoke a command which need to be run at your pc from your phone's shell. To programatically push a file from your system, you need to run `adb push` command in your PC. you can accept this a answer if the solution answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to install an application from the command line

```
adb install example.apk
```

Comment: then please check this url : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android

Comment: Thanks for this link, I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score -1):

```
Before execute `adb shell pm install`, run "adb root" command firstly.
```

if you rooted the device, this step could be omitted.

Comment: When i try this command in the terminal, i am getting error as - "adbd cannot run as root in production builds"