# Xamarin Android 10 Install APK - No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, xamarin.android, apk, android-install-apk, android-10.0

I want to install a 3rd party app from the filesystem from my xamarin android app. The code I used successfully before Android 10 was pretty straightforward and easy.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            Uri data = Uri.FromFile(file);

            intent.SetDataAndType(data, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

            context.StartActivity(intent);
```

This code does not work on Android 10 because of ACTION_VIEW and ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE were deprecated in Android 10. Looks like we now need to use the PackageInstaller API.

I tried to write a method using the PackageInstaller API. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Code with PackageInstaller API

```
 public static void InstallPackageAndroidQAndAbove(Context context, string filePath, string packageName)
    {

        var packageInstaller = context.PackageManager.PackageInstaller;
        var sessionParams = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstallMode.FullInstall);
        sessionParams.SetAppPackageName(packageName);
        int sessionId = packageInstaller.CreateSession(sessionParams);
        var session = packageInstaller.OpenSession(sessionId);

        var input = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var output = session.OpenWrite(packageName, 0, -1);

        input.CopyTo(output);

        output.Close();
        input.Close();
        input.Dispose();

        session.Fsync(output);

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, sessionId, new Intent(Intent.ActionInstallPackage), 0);
        session.Commit(pendingIntent.IntentSender);

    }
```

An exception "Unrecognized stream" occurs during the call.

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried to use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605040/11104068 but edit the uri to be a local file

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either.

Comment: I hope you are checking the Runtime Permission for `INSTALL_PACKAGES`

Comment: i am giving the permission during installation / manifest. also the error message would be more specific then i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xamarin Android Code for installing an apk with the PackageInstaller API.

```
//Change to your package name
    const string PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION =
                "com.example.android.apis.content.SESSION_API_PACKAGE_INSTALLED";

     public static void InstallPackageAndroidQAndAbove(Context context, string filePath)
            {

                var packageInstaller = context.PackageManager.PackageInstaller;
                var sessionParams = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstallMode.FullInstall);
                int sessionId = packageInstaller.CreateSession(sessionParams);
                var session = packageInstaller.OpenSession(sessionId);

                addApkToInstallSession(filePath, session);

                // Create an install status receiver.
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, context.Class);
                intent.SetAction(Globals.PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
                IntentSender statusReceiver = pendingIntent.IntentSender;

                // Commit the session (this will start the installation workflow).
                session.Commit(statusReceiver);

            }

     private static void addApkToInstallSession(string filePath, PackageInstaller.Session session)
            {
                using (var input = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (var packageInSession = session.OpenWrite("package", 0, -1))
                    {
                        input.CopyTo(packageInSession);
                        packageInSession.Close();
                    }
                    input.Close();
                }
                //That this is necessary could be a Xamarin bug.
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();

            }

// Note: this Activity must run in singleTop launchMode for it to be able to receive the //intent
     protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
            {
                base.OnNewIntent(intent);

                Bundle extras = intent.Extras;

                if (Globals.PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION.Equals(intent.Action))
                {
                    int status = extras.GetInt(PackageInstaller.ExtraStatus);
                    String message = extras.GetString(PackageInstaller.ExtraStatusMessage);

                    switch (status)
                    {
                        case (int)PackageInstallStatus.PendingUserAction:
                            // This test app isn't privileged, so the user has to confirm the install.
                            Intent confirmIntent = (Intent)extras.Get(Intent.ExtraIntent);
                            StartActivity(confirmIntent);
                            break;
                        case (int)PackageInstallStatus.Success:
                            Toast.MakeText(this, "Install succeeded!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                            break;
                        case (int)PackageInstallStatus.Failure:
                        case (int)PackageInstallStatus.FailureAborted:
                        case (int)PackageInstallStatus.FailureBlocked:
                        case (int)PackageInstallStatus.FailureConflict:
                        case (int)PackageInstallStatus.FailureIncompatible:
                        case (int)PackageInstallStatus.FailureInvalid:
                        case (int)PackageInstallStatus.FailureStorage:
                            Toast.MakeText(this, "Install failed! " + status + ", " + message,
                                    ToastLength.Long).Show();
                            break;
                        default:
                            Toast.MakeText(this, "Unrecognized status received from installer: " + status,
                                   ToastLength.Long).Show();
                            break;
                    }
                }


            }
```

Comment: This code indeed installs new version (thumbs up) but for some reason it fails to reopen installed app. Did you encounter the same problem?

Comment: I got `write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)` while closing the `packageInSession`. The file I'm trying to load is an apk I deployed from VisualStudio in debug. (basically the same one is running).

Comment: @Oiproks check out this thread https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/180083/ebadf-bad-file-descriptor-with-andoid-10-target-with-packageinstaller-api/p1?new=1

Comment: @Oiproks please refer to this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889386/1465881

Comment: I have found this same code in a lot of entries, so I think it is a copy paste. You say about replacing the const string PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION with the package name, but don't say about changing the whole string or only a part of it, so it is not clear. Also you use session.OpenWrite("package", 0, -1), but are you sure that "package" musn't be the package name again? I have tried to replace and replace strings and it doesn't work.