# Prompt apk Installation not working in android 10 using PackageInstaller API

Tags: android, packageinstaller

My app downloads an APK from server. For below Android 10 versions, after apk download the install prompt is working as intended but in Android 10 the apk gets downloaded using PackageInstaller API as mentioned in this link 
[Installing apk that updates the same app fails on Android 10; java.lang.SecurityException: Files still open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374527/installing-apk-that-updates-the-same-app-fails-on-android-10-java-lang-security,this)  but the installation prompt is not working, user has to manually install the app from the notification bar by clicking on the apk which i don't want.
Also in my code, callback is not received in onNewIntent() in my MainActivity after the apk gets downloaded, do this may be the reason the apk installation prompt is not happening?
I have used the same code block as mentioned in the link above.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: till now no answers, strange:(

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: No:(
Still looking for a feasible solution or Reply