# Is there any way to use PackageInstaller below API level 21?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0, packageinstaller

My application minSdkVersion is 19 and application installs 3rd party app using following code,

```
Intent intent = Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(android.net.Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(APK_PATH)),
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I have Added permission in manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

The above code is working well up to android version 9, but in Android 10 is not working and no logs found. I have gone through some docs,  ACTION_VIEW or ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE is deprecated on Android 10. **PackageInstaller** is a new API for install 3rd party apps but PackageInstaller is added in API level 21.

Is there any way to use PackageInstaller below API level 21? How can I install 3rd party app in Android 10??

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/41663453 it may help you

Comment: "Is there any way to use PackageInstaller below API level 21?" - no. Use PackageInstaller if device SDK version is 29 or above. Otherwise, use your current solution.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu my application minimum sdk support is API level 19 but PackageInstaller need 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to integrate both APIs you can use simple if statement that decides which API you should use.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.L) {
    // use PackageInstaller. No errors, no exceptions 
} else {
    Intent intent = Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(android.net.Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(APK_PATH)),
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
}
```

`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is the SDK number of which is used on a device where your application is running.

`Build.VERSION_CODES.L` is a constant value:

```
/**
 * Temporary until we completely switch to {@link #LOLLIPOP}.
 * @hide
 */
public static final int L = 21;
```

*That is the official way to handle SDK differences. [Here is an example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running?hl=ru#java) from Android documentation. Search for `>= Build.VERSION_CODES` on that page.*

Comment: my application minimum sdk support is API level 19 but PackageInstaller need 21.

Comment: That is why I posted a snipped with `if` statement where you can check what is the API level of the device your application is running. `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.L` if this statement is true then you can use `PackageInstaller`.