# Installing APK from SMBfile: how to get the Uri

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, apk

I'm trying to setup an updated for my app at work. I have set it up to check for the version on a file and then try to install the new APK if the version don't match.
I'm trying to follow the guide [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android) but it doesn't seem to work with SMB paths.

The first issue I have is that for some reason, I seem to not have the Uri.Parse() available. second issue, it seems to be asking for a string, I was wondering if there is a way to make it work with SMBfiles.

```
string path = @"smb://Domain/Share/IT/Androids/Picking.apk";
var auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("Domain", "Username", "Pwd");
SmbFile file = new SmbFile(path, auth);
```

If that matters, the Uri seems to come from system. Is it another Uri from somewhere else I should be using?

```
Intent PromptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ActionView).SetDataAndType(Uri.Parse(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");' 
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

is what I havebut I get an error that Uri.Parse is inaccessible with its protection level. Furthermore, I don't think Uri.Parse will work with a smb path rather than a file path.

Comment: `.I'm trying to follow the guide found here` Well post the code you tried.

Comment: `the Uri seems to come from system.` Sorry, i have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: `I seem to not have the Uri.Parse() available.` Why not? Please elaborate. `it seems to be asking for a string,` Yes. What is the problem with that? I see a nice string in youir code.

Comment: @blackapps there we go. I updated it. Sorry I got lost in the comment editor.

Comment: I cannot see that you try to use an smbpath.or smburl or whatever. And can you post in such a way that we dont have to scrol horizontally? WHy are you using a File file?

Comment: @blackapps mostly out of habit. I usually load my files as SMBFiles to manipulate them. I'm not well versed in android work, so I work with what I know.

I managed to find the issue, I changed SetDataAndType(Uri.Parse) to SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Parse). I was using the wrong Uri.
Now I just need to find how to use the "StartActivity" as my program seems not to know of its existence.

Comment: We still cannot see that you use Android.Net.Parse. And we still cannot see that you ise an smb path. And we still do not know what File would be.