# General question about uploading and app and reffering to it

Tags: java, android, upload

My free app (which is not on the market yet) has a button that supposed to lead the user to the paid app... to do so im using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.example"));
startActivity(intent);
```

the question is what do i put instead of com.android.example? Is it the name of the package that i made when i first created the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the id that Market uses is the same as the package name as it is specified in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.etc.etc.yourpackagename">
    ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the name of the package of your paid app.

Answer (score 0):

There is [an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893350/how-to-launch-the-market-intent-in-give-feedback-mode-on-android) not about the same problem but in the question-post, there is a working code which does what you want to do.

If you had simply googled "android intent to market app intent", you would have found it...