# How to use "Send Feeback", FeedbackActivity, in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there a sample of using **com.google.android.feedback.FeedbackActivity** like it's used in the Google+ App to send any feedback?

I tried to start it with

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.feedback",  "com.google.android.feedback.FeedbackActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

but I only get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.feedback/com.google.android.feedback.FeedbackActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: You could look in it's source code which extras it expects

Comment: Where can I find the sources of that? I thinks it's closed source - I'm not good in reverse engineering. That's why I posted the question here.

Comment: have you add it with manifest file?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559267/how-to-use-intent-action-app-error-as-a-means-for-a-feedback-framework-in-andr

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Solution for all APIs

### I have added all my research and related posts

I have been looking for the best solution for this for a while. Please look at the Google "MyTracks" application which is open source and on Google Code here:

https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/TrackListActivity.java

Look at how they handle compatibility between API levels with their API Adapter classes:

https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks#mytracks%2Futil

### Handling Menus:

**Based on API => 14 (allow feedback):**

```
menu.findItem(R.id.track_list_feedback)
    .setVisible(ApiAdapterFactory.getApiAdapter().isGoogleFeedbackAvailable());
```

This will remove the button "Send Feedback" if API is lower than 14.

### Sending Feedback:

https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/util/GoogleFeedbackUtils.java

**Based on API => 14 (send feedback):**

```
public class GoogleFeedbackUtils {

  private static final String TAG = GoogleFeedbackUtils.class.getSimpleName();

  private GoogleFeedbackUtils() {}

  /**
   * Binds the Google Feedback service.
   * 
   * @param context the context
   */
  public static void bindFeedback(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_BUG_REPORT);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.gms", "com.google.android.gms.feedback.LegacyBugReportService"));
    ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
      public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        try {
          service.transact(Binder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION, Parcel.obtain(), null, 0);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "RemoteException", e);
        }
      }

        @Override
      public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {}
    };
    // Bind to the service after creating it if necessary
    context.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  }
}
```

### Code for menu:

https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/TrackListActivity.java

**Snippet from source, Based on API => 14:**

```
 @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.track_list_feedback:
        GoogleFeedbackUtils.bindFeedback(this);
        return true;
      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
```

### Solution for API 10+:

Read here:
[How to use Intent.ACTION_APP_ERROR as a means for a "feedback" framework in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559267/how-to-use-intent-action-app-error-as-a-means-for-a-feedback-framework-in-andr)
and here:
http://blog.tomtasche.at/2012/10/use-built-in-feedback-mechanism-on.html

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)  
private void sendFeedback() {
    try {
        int i = 3 / 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    ApplicationErrorReport report = new ApplicationErrorReport();
    report.packageName = report.processName = getApplication().getPackageName();
    report.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    report.type = ApplicationErrorReport.TYPE_CRASH;
    report.systemApp = false;

    ApplicationErrorReport.CrashInfo crash = new ApplicationErrorReport.CrashInfo();
    crash.exceptionClassName = e.getClass().getSimpleName();
    crash.exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(writer);
    e.printStackTrace(printer);

    crash.stackTrace = writer.toString();

    StackTraceElement stack = e.getStackTrace()[0];
    crash.throwClassName = stack.getClassName();
    crash.throwFileName = stack.getFileName();
    crash.throwLineNumber = stack.getLineNumber();
    crash.throwMethodName = stack.getMethodName();

    report.crashInfo = crash;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.feedback", "com.google.android.feedback.FeedbackActivity");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BUG_REPORT, report);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

## Solution for All APIs

**Bottom line:** Application report will be made for all phones with API 10+ and application installed or information can be sent through email.

**1. Make sure the user has the application installed**

```
if (applicationExist("com.google.android.feedback"))
```

**2. If the user has the application installed, run the Feedback application directly**

```
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.feedback", "com.google.android.feedback.FeedbackActivity");
```

**3. If the user does not have application installed, send feedback to Email**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)  
private void sendFeedback() {
    try {
        int i = 3 / 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ApplicationErrorReport report = new ApplicationErrorReport();
        report.packageName = report.processName = getApplication().getPackageName();
        report.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        report.type = ApplicationErrorReport.TYPE_NONE;
        report.systemApp = false;

        ApplicationErrorReport.CrashInfo crash = new ApplicationErrorReport.CrashInfo();
        crash.exceptionClassName = e.getClass().getSimpleName();
        crash.exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(writer);
        e.printStackTrace(printer);

        crash.stackTrace = writer.toString();

        StackTraceElement stack = e.getStackTrace()[0];
        crash.throwClassName = stack.getClassName();
        crash.throwFileName = stack.getFileName();
        crash.throwLineNumber = stack.getLineNumber();
        crash.throwMethodName = stack.getMethodName();

        report.crashInfo = crash;

        try
        {
            if (applicationExist("com.google.android.feedback"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.feedback", "com.google.android.feedback.FeedbackActivity");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BUG_REPORT, report);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "burrowsapps@gmail.com" });
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().loadLabel(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()).toString()+"("+getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationInfo().packageName, 0).versionName+")"+" Contact Form | Device: "+Build.MANUFACTURER+" "+Build.DEVICE+"("+Build.MODEL+") API: "+Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
                intent.setType("plain/html");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) { }
    }
}

private boolean applicationExist(String uri)
{
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    boolean exists = false;
    try
    {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        exists = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }

    return exists;
}
```

Comment: Where is the feedback send to when using GoogleFeedbackUtils? (For API => 14)

Comment: @GerritHoekstra The link I provided to the MyTracks app located on GoogleCode.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding but I mean where does the feedback send to when you submit the feedback form when using `GoogleFeedbackUtils`? To the `Android Developer Console`, email, Google headquarters (I have a doubt about it), or somewhere else?

Comment: @GerritHoekstra Crash Report -> Android Developer Console and Email -> Your email

Comment: This answer will crash on api 21+. Service Intents must now be explicit

Comment: To fix add the line intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gms");

Comment: This is from almost 2 years ago. I updated the answer.

Comment: @JaredBurrows where does the feedback send to when you submit the feedback form when using GoogleFeedbackUtils?  (For API => 14)